# How can I open another website in Shadowbox JS

Tags: javascript, shadowbox

How do you open an external URL in `shadowbow` like I've been trying to here?

```html
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function s20(){
        shadowbox.open("http://www.webmuse.co.uk/");
    }
</script>

<a onclick="s20()">name</a>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571936/opening-shadowbox-from-javascript-function

Comment: Thank's so much man - Digigizmo